# Exponential functions of a complex number. I can't get it right.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function

**Question:**
Prove that $\frac{e^Z}{e^W} = e^{z-w}$

**My Attempt:**
The given equation on left-hand side can be re-written as $e^z.e^{-w}$.
Let $z = x + iy$ and $w = u + iv$.
$exp(w) = e^u(cosv+isinv)$. This can be re-written by expanding the brackets and yields $exp(w) = e^ucosv + (e^usinv)i$
After calculation, $exp(-w) = \frac{cosv}{e^u} - \frac{sinv}{e^u}i$

Now, calculating $e^z.e^{-w}$ yields the following:

$$\frac{e^x}{e^u}[(cosy.cosv + siny.sinv) + i(cosv.siny - sinv.cosy)]$$

**Problem:**
The answer is all correct expect that the signs are wrong within the brackets. Where did I go wrong ?

**Update:**
Looking at the notes given to me by Prof. Robert Israel (who is also a community member), I got this:
[image]
**and I guess my answer is indeed right**, I did not mess up the signs :)

Comment: Possibly $e^{-w}$ is screwed up.

Comment: What you need is here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities

Comment: How did you get $y$ into the expression for $e^w$?

Comment: @copper.hat typo there. It is a V. Correcting.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Look at the subtraction formulas for sine and cosine.

Comment: @Lubin you and me posted the same thing simultaneously :) Look at the update :)